# Filter json data based on querystring

Tags: jquery, json

I'm learning json and is at lost at filtering the json data when I need to show persons whose job is a reporter.

```
 {
"person": [
   {
       "firstName": "Clark",
       "lastName": "Gable",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 20
   },
   {
       "firstName": "Bruce",
       "lastName": "Willis",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30
   },
   {
       "firstName": "James",
       "lastName": "Parker",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 40
   }
]
}
```

the page is called with a querystring I'm using the job_param as the variable from another function

```
http://jsontest/person.html?job=reporter



var job_param = gup( 'job' );
alert("job selected is: " + job_param);


$(function() {
var people = [];
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
   "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td><a href=\"category.html?cat=" + f.firstName + "\">Go</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
 });

});

});
```

html file

```
<table id= "userdata" border="2">
<thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Go</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I could just generate a new json file from mysql to show only reporters in the list, but I don't think it's how it should be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the query string value first:

```
var job = GetQueryStringValue('job');
```

Then compare the json with the variable:

```
$.each(data.person, function (key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value.firstName);
    if (value.job == job) {
        // If person reporter, do this
    } else {
        // If person is not a reporter, do this
    }
});
```

Comment: 'Reporter' is a dynamic value based on a querystring.

Comment: You can use the updated code then, where _GetQueryStringValue_ is just a function you can use to get the value before comaparing.

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like:

```
$(function() {
var people = [];
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
      if(f.job=='Reporter')
      {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td><a href=\"category.html?cat=" + f.firstName + "\">Go</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
         });
      }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

the Javascript Library "underscore" http://underscorejs.org/#filter has good tools for filtering linke that:

```
reporters = _.filter(array_of_people, function(p){ return p.job == "Reporter"; });
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/sXfxD/

Comment: Thanks for the library and the example. Definitely something I'm looking forward to learn.

Comment: hint: you can express your gratitude by giving +1   ;-)